# Add a datagridview column from another form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two forms and a datagridview which is in the form1.Im trying to add a new column by clicking in a button from form2.Like that:

```
 Form2


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();

        form1.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("test" , "test");

    }
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

This will not work as your real form1 is already there, I pressume. Instead create a reference to it in form2 and load it in form2's constructor!

Here are the steps:

1. the local reference to form1 in form2's variables:  `Form1 form1`
2. When opening form2 pass a reference to form1 in the constructor:

   `form2 = new Form2(this);`
3. Store it in the local refence in the constructor on form2:

   ```
   public Form2(Form1 form1_)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       form1 = form1_;
   }
   ```

Now you are all set to use Form1 and its public properties and controls. To use `form1.dataGridView1` you must make it public first, though. (Or create a public reference to it..)

Comment: I tried what u wrote but it is still not working. There is no error, but the information is not passing between the forms. ):

Comment: "There is no error" No that's a start! Your code doesn't really pass on information, does it? It creates a new column "test" in the DGV. Have you deleted the line `Form1 form1 = new Form1();
` from the ButtonClick? It would hide the refence to the real form..

Comment: I cant do that: form2 = new Form2 (Form1 this); 
in form1 when I open form2