# How do I access DataGridView from another form?

Tags: c#

I want to access a DataGridView from another form. I just want to get a value from DataGridView and show it in a textbox located in another form.

As shown in the photo: 
I click Edit line button and Form2 pops up, so when i click button1, textbox1 should have the value of row[0] cell[0] (which is "1") but instead i get this Error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Is there anything I am missing? I made DataGridView Modifiers = Public but still didn't work. please help thank you.

[image: Photo]

Comment: You should take a look at delegates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019402/when-why-to-use-delegates

Comment: Please paste your code, not a screenshot of your code.

Comment: Never access `SelectedRows` without checking if there are any selected rows! Also your new form1 is just that: __new__, not the other one! Eric shows you one common approach to pass a reference out. Instead of the DGV you could just as well __pass out the form1 itself!__!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a datagridview collumn from another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186519/add-a-datagridview-collumn-from-another-form)

Comment: TaW, I am confused can you please explain more about passing a reference or please show me an example. thank you

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedRows` refers to rows that are selected. You should use the `Rows` property instead.

Comment: Ryck, I changed it from SelectedRows  to Rows but still did not work. any suggestion? thank you

Comment: Yes. I see you are creating a new Form1 object. You need a reference to the one you created the Form2 object from. One way to do this is to pass a reference when creating Form2. You could add a constructor that takes a Form1 reference and then save it as a class member. There are "better" ways to do this, but you aren't asking for a tutorial in design patterns.

Comment: I have been searching and reading about what you said but I got confused. can you please explain more or give an example. all what I want is: to pass a value from DataGridView in form1 to a textbox in form2. thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Create properties in `Form2`

   `public int Qty {get; set;}`
  2.

---

```
  private void Edit_Line_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
  {
     Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Qty=this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
     if(frm2.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
     {
        this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value = frm2.textBox1.Text;
     }
  }
```

This is just an idea, you have to work around to get exact output.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this work fine for me.**

Enjoy...!!!

[image]

**I selected Row contaning Anjum text**
Output
[image]

As same:
[image]

> **Code Form1**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewCellAcessing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] {
                    "Anjum"});
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] {
                    "Khuram"});
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] {
                    "Shahzad"});
        }

       

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Edit(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
   
            form2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

> **Code Form2**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewCellAcessing
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
        }
        public void Edit(string Values) {
           
                textBox1.Text = Values;

           
        }
    }
}
```